# Finding the right opponent for adventurers

Tags: science-based, creature-design

Turns out, creating a species of essentially immortal humans with the minds of hardcore World of Warcraft and D&D players was a horrible idea.

To prevent these vile parasites from destroying all life, Herr Professor Doctor designs a creature (*The Nightman and its lackeys*) that could fight them. Of course, the end result will inadvertently turn against its creator.

But now, he asked for your help.

**Adventurers are:**

- **Immortal**: They respawn after death at indestructible checkpoints, which relocate themselves regularly to prevent [spawn camping](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spawn%20camping). Tampering with checkpoints is not possible.
- **Murderous and Unreasonable**: They kill to get EXP, they collect EXP to get stronger, they get stronger to get more EXP, no higher or rational goals, just to become the very best, like no one ever was.
- **Nomadic:** They rarely establish a base and even if they do, it's temporary. They know how to hunker down.
- **Strong:** Every adventurer will get to the peak of human athletic and fine-motor capabilities.
- **Independent:** The apocalypse left many USPs, AR-15s and a plenty of ammunition, laying around in dangerous zones, perfect for an adventurer to loot. There's also a species of algae called *mana*, it's very resilient, purifies water and is very nutritious.
- **Tactical:** Adventurers organize into groups, where the specializations of each member add together into a powerful team. And unlike others, adventurers experience combat in "turns", so they can optimize their strategy and coordinate their moves through encrypted telepathic channels.

**Specific data:**

- Numbers: 1 million, the total population of the world: 9 million
- Respawn time: 36 hours
- Spawnpoints: Spawnpoints can increase their numbers in response to hostile activity by non-adventurers.
- Spawnpoints are immobile while an adventurer (alive) is inside. Spawnpoints typically choose areas with low population density.

**Can I use help?**

Tests using ordinary monsters to combat adventurers all resulted in failure:

> Not even five turns in and every test subject, even dragons were
>   reduced to a whimpering mess:
>   *"Mommy, please help!"*
>   *"I just want to go home!"*
>   *"I don't  want to die!"*
>   Is it really that hard to fight a battle, you cannot win, against superhuman 
>   serial killers, who will sell you
>   on eBay organ by organ!? Okay fine, **I leave them out of this**, das ist mein Kampf, after all.

**SO, Herr Professor Doctor needs to:**

- Find all weakness, specific to adventurers.
- Make <s>The Night King</s> The Nightman and its lackeys in a way to exploit the weaknesses.

**He wants to:**

- Hinder the adventurers on a large scale, as much as possible.
- Minimalize civilian casualties.

**You're not allowed to:**

- Use magic (**neither** can adventurers)
- Equip them (Nightman and the gang) with tech, more advanced than the **late medieval stuff**
- You can modify them genetically as much as you want, but you're not allowed to go outside the boundaries of biology.

Concentrate on the necessary attributes/abilities of the nightman to be successful, attributes and abilities that will be **integrated** into it. I will handle the open-ended and unnecessary details.

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: Is there a radius in which the spawn point must be located, or is it random on the entire planet/continent/map? Also, how many adventurers are there? How fast is their respawn period?

Comment: @L.Dutch It's an open ended creature design to create the biological monstrosity that drives his plot.

Comment: @ClayDeitas I added those parts to the question.

Comment: @ClayDeitas, from [what question should I not ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "asking an open-ended, hypothetical question"

Comment: @L.Dutch It's open ended, but within the scope of what worldbuilding typically allows.

Comment: @ClayDeitas Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Mephistopheles, it's your question, you have to elaborate and clarify

Comment: @L.Dutch I did, I just don't know if it was successful.

Comment: @Mephistopheles How does adventurer telepathy work? Does it permit complex communication? Or solely things like "Use attack 1", "Dodge", etc? Also, where does this ability originate from? Is there some sort of telepathy organ within the adventurer's body? Or is there a specialized brain region that does it? The answers to these questions basically make or break the solution I'm currently writing up.

Comment: @AngelPray Basically, a fancy radio, linked directly to the brain

Comment: @Mephistopheles Oh dear... Well, my solution is no more, then. I'll try and come up with another one.

Comment: The Lackeys are Tsetse flies living near the respawn points: in 15 days the heroes have insomnia, dizziness, confusion. 15 days later they are in coma. When they respawn, you infect them again.

Comment: The OP does not specify, but does the solution need to be fun and exciting for role playing adventurers?  Or do you just need these bozos out of commission?

Comment: @AlbertoYagos One day, they will develop immunity against that.

Comment: We all know that Nightman cannot defeat Dayman, who's a master of karate and friendship for everyone. Why even try?

Comment: "Find all weakness, specific to adventurers."  That statement makes this question too broad by definition.  The SE model is "one-specific-question/one-best-answer."  [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  VTC as too broad until one (and only one) specific question is asked.

Comment: By the way, why is he Herr Professor Doctor instead of Herr Professor Doktor? Was he unable to get into a graduate program in the fatherland so he had to go to Grenada or something? I don't think I'm being too suspicious in checking him out before I agree t work for him, am I?

Comment: I think its actually even more simple than creating a new creature. All you need to do is enable PVP for all participants with no safe zones. Why kill the adventurers when they will happily kill each other for you?

Answer (score 4):

**Lotus.**

[image: lotus eaters]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lotos-Eaters

In the Odyssey, they find an island inhabited by the Lotus Eaters.  Once you eat of lotus, that is all you want to do.  The men who eat lotus just want to stay and eat lotus.  It is nice.  They cry when they are tied up and carried back to the ship.

This is what your uberadventurers need.  Something to stay their drive to kill and advance and die and live again - and instead, be content to dream .  Tennyson wrote a poem about it that seems very relevant to your situation.  Here, a lotus eater speaks.

> Let us alone. Time driveth onward fast,
>
> And in a little while our lips are dumb.
>
> Let us alone. What is it that will last?
>
> All things are taken from us, and become
>
> Portions and parcels of the dreadful past.
>
> Let us alone. What pleasure can we have
>
> To war with evil? Is there any peace
>
> In ever climbing up the climbing wave?
>
> All things have rest, and ripen toward the grave
>
> In silence—ripen, fall, and cease:
>
> Give us long rest or death, dark death, or dreamful ease.

Your superhumans are tired.  They will be glad to rest.  No-one will force them back to their old ways.

As regards the Nightman, he is aptly named.  The Nightman is the Sandman -  Morpheus, god of dreams.

[image: sandman]
[source](https://www.theverge.com/2016/11/4/13517450/sandman-writer-quits-only-tv-neil-gaiman)

Comment: How do I get them under the influence of the nightman?

Comment: @Mephistopheles You just show that the ones using it are in bliss. And as it goes for most drugs, people may get curious and want a try.

Comment: Since the adventurers are not normal people with normal desires, the traditional Lotus may not work on them—but a different drug that makes them think they're in Valhalla hacking through frost giants and gods left and right, while their bodies are actually just lying on the ground in ketamine catatonia, should work just fine. (And they probably don't need much encouragement to have exactly those kinds of dreams.)

Comment: @abarnert - There is an episode of Justice League that riffs on that.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHqEScjQfsQ. The parasite causes people to have happy dreams.  Superman dreams of what his life would have been on Krypton if he had grown up normally there.  A parasite gets on Batman too.  It is quite an episode.

Comment: @Willk Thanks; I'd never seen that before, but I do somewhat remember the comic it was based on. Good adaptation, but I miss Batman lying about his fantasy. (Also, if they had to cut Robin for contrast reasons, why not replace him with Wally—whose fantasy would be exactly like the real world except that he can run even faster?)

Answer (score 0):

1. The Nightman needs to be highly mobile. I recommend something like a Azhdarchidae which is both highly mobile on land and in the air. It can cause distress to adventurers by circling behind them, dropping trees in the way, or other such things.
2. The Nightman's most important function is as a queen to produce "henchmen." Henchmen are just small versions of the Nightman, highly mobile and quick to proliferate. Estimates give Ashdarchidaes a seven day period between hatching and flying, but you could speed that up even a bit more. The Nightman's job is to fly around avoiding adventurers and laying eggs everywhere it can.
3. The Henchmen's main goal is to disrupt the adventurers supply chains. Puking up strong acids and the like to corrode weapons and ammo, destroying them. It will take a lot of food and water to support such a thing, but there job also includes eating any and all mana and other food sources they find to keep it away from adventurers.
4. They Henchmen's secondary goal is to keep adventurers away from settlements. This sometimes means they will attack adventurers head on, and then slowly retreat in order to lure the adventurers away.
5. The Nightman has to be pitch black as the night, the goal being to look intimidating in light, but be a perfect stealth machine at night.
6. The henchmen have sharp claws and beaks. They should only attack in large numbers, and should always aim for the neck. The only time they attack is at night. Probably need echolocation to track enemies and not run into each other.
7. Drop stuff on adventurers. No need to just let the adventurers run around during the day when they can't attack directly. They can poop on, puke on, and drop stuff on any adventurer without a dedicated anti air gun. If they discover an adventurer with a shotgun or other practical anti air gun, they will become a priority target, and a larger swarm will come to eliminate them and destroy the aforementioned weapon.
8. Henchmen can grow up to five feet tall, and then lay their own eggs. The hatchlings of henchmen are infertile and grow to a maximum of two feet, but function the same as a henchmen.
9. The greatest difference between Henchmen and the Nightman is intelligence, where henchmen follow a hive like plan that evenly distributes them and allows them to coordinate movements, but the Nightman has high levels of forethought, self awareness, and can gain knowledge from many sources. Henchmen typically only learn from exsperience, and through communication with other henchmen.
10. ( The Nightman may be self conscious about its appearance, angered that it has no more functionality than its lackies, who are literally an inferior clone of itself. Maybe that's why it calls itself the Nightman instead of a bird related pun. )
11. The Nightman doesn't feel a loss at henchmen dying. It only cares about using their full power by maintaining a high population.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhdarchidae

Answer (score 0):

> Find all weakness, specific to adventurers.

Their all-consuming need for XP is their weakness. It affects all adventurers, and no one but adventurers.<sup>1</sup>

Unless you throw super-powerful monsters at them, they will get more XP for killing each other than for anything else they can do.<sup>2</sup>

Since this is tagged `science-based`, let me include an equation:

$$8000 \gt 8$$

---

They may be too dumb to think of that themselves, but once they do, you're basically done.

So, the ideal candidate for the Nightman position is an experienced Director of Marketing, who can demonstrate a history of successful launch campaigns.<sup>3</sup>

And he will spend all of your resources on hiring graphic designers, advertisers, and propagandists and enabling them to actualize their campaigns. You want posters, leaflets, criers, whatever (Nightman knows the target market, and how to reach it, far better than you, me, or Herr Professor Doctor; that's what you're paying him for), something like this:

> **Leveling up is YOUR responsibility.**
>
> - Slime: 1xp.
> - Kobold: 8xp.
> - Your fellow adventurer who's charging that kobold: 8000xp.
>
> And your buddy will just respawn if you kill him.
>
> **What do YOU think you should do?**

… maybe with a subtle background image like this:

[image: Backstabbing]

And now, instead of fighting D&D parties, you're fighting Paranoia parties.<sup>4</sup> Which means you don't have to fight them. All you really have to do is not get too close while they're fragging each other.<sup>5</sup>

---

This minimizes collateral damage because the adventurers are only killing each other rather than slaughtering your helpless innocent Uruk-Hai, and because they're doing it as close as possible to the random spawn points instead of fighting right in the middle of your population and resource concentrations (aka quest targets).

---

<sub>1. I'm assuming that in your world, dockworkers and nurses either don't need XP, or get it from doing dockworking and nurse stuff rather than from murder.</sub>

<sub>2. They might lose their special paladin abilities or something, but better a 10th level fighter than a 3rd level paladin, right?</sub>

<sub>3. You can settle for a Leni Riefenstahl or Joseph Goebbels type if there's nobody quite *that* evil in your world.</sub>

<sub>4. Actually, even *better* than Paranoia parties. A Troubleshooter still has to be motivated by the fact that some of his colleagues may be filthy mutants or dirty Commie spies (not to mention keeping his own secret society membership secret), and has to justify his Shooting of that Trouble to Friend Computer after the fact. An Adventurer only needs to notice the CL of his colleagues to be motivated, and needs no further justification than that.</sub>

<sub>5. Of course eventually they'll get so powerful that their infighting can level continents. But adventurers get bored of the prime material plane and start screwing with the gods long before that's a problem. *Plane Shift* is 3 levels below *Earthquake*.</sub>

Comment: Herr Professor Doctor was supposed to minimize collateral damage, not encourage it.

Comment: @Mephistopheles Yes, and? Keeping the adventurers murdering each other instead of murdering helpless slimes, and fighting right near the random spawn points instead of near concentrations of population and industry (aka quest locations) does that.

Comment: So, you suggest hiring a bunch of internet trolls, CNN, and Joseph Goebbels to make FAKE NEWS to spark a civil war among adventurers?

Comment: @Mephistopheles No, because in a civil war, at least half of them are on the winning side, and then you have to deal with the winners. I want them murdering each other one on one, so the worst-case scenario is one winner who's too busy watching his back (because he's now the biggest XP target in the world) to bother with us.

Comment: @Mephistopheles And Goebbels or an army of Russian trolls is probably not going to do that as well as, say, Jay Chiat—or, even better, whoever made the decision at Apple to _hire_ Chiat/Day for their ad campaigns. Because you're not trying to confuse and mislead people so they don't believe the truth or act against their own interests, you're just trying to get them to notice something that is _actually true_, and to see it in the best possible light.

Comment: The problem is that, in the end, this would create a Walpurgisnacht or Kriemhild Gretchen, that is undefeatable, and prompts others to hide from it and prey on weaker targets like ancient red dragons and lower-tier players.

Comment: @Mephistopheles I don't understand what you're saying. Walpurgisnacht is when everyone prays to protect themselves from a conspiracy of evil witches, so I don't see how that's relevant here. From a quick search, it seems like Kriemhild Gretchen is a powerful witch that the good guys can't defeat; the answer there is that all of the other adventurers are trying to defeat her so the good guys don't have to—and, meanwhile, she's off fighting archdevils and gods in the outer planes, far from your innocent red dragons.

Comment: @Mephistopheles As for preying on lower-level players: of course some of them will do that, but who cares? Herr Professor Doctor is not charged with trying to protect adventurers, is he?

Answer (score 0):

Create an adventurer ecosystem that will keep them busy until eternity.

Your nightman is Evil, most of his lackeys are Evil and will for now be termed "Evil Henchmen (EH)", but you also create a a subdivision that for the time being will be called "Adventurer Relations (AR's)".

EH's would fulfill the opposition role. They'll create dens, build Evil lairs (™) and create Evil Plots (™).

AR's would create towns, villages and cities near EH activity. AR's would also have certain traits, such as being a spokesman who asks adventurers to slay nearby EH's or investigate EH activity, some will be prone to social problems and ask adventurers to clear it up or make moral choices, others will have the dreaded and feared traits of getting lost all the time in dangerous area's (protect the NPC quest) or requiring/losing certain highly specific objects (fetch quest!). The more time consuming quests would be high-level and will include entire towns who will keep adventurers busy for weeks, months or even years.

To make matters worse (or better), the EH's will attempt to replicate a more Dark Souls environment that's gruelling for adventurers to fight through, with high-level monsters mixed in with the low-level stuff to ensure an adventurer could be busy for extreme long times before they even pass the early levels and get to fight higher level hordes.